# Cant mount drive, could this be a zero-length partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/k
mount: /dev/sdc1: can't read superblock
```

---

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/sdc
mke2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
/dev/sdc is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
183148544 inodes, 732566646 blocks
36628332 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
22357 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544
```

---

Testdisk analyzed GPT and one partition,but after and deep search in analyze ,the disk seems to be dead "read I/O error"

```
Jul 31 00:19:24 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 7970.066739] ata3.00: configured 
for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
Jul 31 00:19:24 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 7970.066770] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
Jul 31 00:19:24 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 7970.066779] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
Jul 31 00:19:24 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 7970.066788] Descriptor sense 
data with sense descriptors (in hex):
Jul 31 00:19:24 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 7970.066793]         72 0b 00 00 
00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
Jul 31 00:19:24 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 7970.066810]         00 00 00 00 
Jul 31 00:19:24 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 7970.066818] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
Add. Sense: No additional sense information
Jul 31 00:19:24 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 7970.066827] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 
CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
Jul 31 00:19:24 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 7970.066843] end_request: I/O 
error, dev sdc, sector 0
Jul 31 00:19:24 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [ 7970.066879] ata3: EH complete
```

anyone for ...

3 TB music collection :(

### Im not able now to put some picture cause of the forum policy . :(

```
    sudo fsck.ext4 -b 102400000 -B 4096 /dev/sdc1

    e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)

    fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc1

    The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2

    filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2

    filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock

    is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:

    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

---

### Why its show ext2 filesystem damn.

this is the mount commands output

```
    sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/k
    mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
    missing codepage or helper program, or other error
    In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
    dmesg | tail  or so
```

this is syslog output when i try to mount the volume

```
   Jul 31 18:04:29 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  709.317917] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
   Jul 31 18:04:29 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  709.317926] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
   Jul 31 18:04:29 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  709.317934] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
    Jul 31 18:04:29 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  709.317949] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:00:c2:02:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
    Jul 31 18:04:29 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  709.317952]          res 41/40:00:c8:02:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
    Jul 31 18:04:29 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  709.317959] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
    Jul 31 18:04:29 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  709.317965] ata3.00: error: { UNC }
    Jul 31 18:04:29 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  709.329953] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
    Jul 31 18:04:29 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  709.329974] ata3: EH complete
    Jul 31 18:04:30 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  710.362452] EXT3-fs (sdc1): error: no journal found
```

---

here is fdisk -l output

```
Disk /dev/sda: 32.0 GB, 32017047552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62533296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001a10f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848    23619583    11706368    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        23621630    62531583    19454977    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        23621632    62531583    19454976   83  Linux

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System                                                                         
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT                                                                            
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.                                                                                

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdd'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.                        


Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sde: 8076 MB, 8076132352 bytes
249 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1021 cylinders, total 15773696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c2243

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1   *          62    15762197     7881068    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Jul 31 00:31:53 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [   114.223612] EXT3-fs (sdc1): error: no journal found
Jul 31 00:35:10 morteza-System-Product-Name kernel: [  311.329522] EXT3-fs (sdc1): error: no journal found

Comment: after shutdown computer and unplug the power the HDD working correctly without I/O error but unable to mount " error:no journal found"and the testdisk analyze GPT nad correct partition and write the info to partition but still wont mount!!

Comment: morteza@morteza-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads/testdisk-6.14-WIP$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/k
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're formatting the entire *disk*, not just a partition: `/dev/sdc` stands for the whole drive, while `/dev/sdc1` is its first partition. You should format and mount *partitions*, not drives.

To troubleshoot, try this:

- re-partition it using `fdisk` (or a GUI like `gparted`). You should re-create the GPT/Partition table
- format the *first* partition (`/dev/sdc1`) as `ext4`
- now try `mount`

If it does not work, please post the output of the following commands:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdc
fsck /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ,yes i know that,but /dev/sdc1 was disappeared  and any command output was "/dev/sdc1 does not exist".the GPT is correct cause the testdisk analyzing it and says find GPT partition table but befor reach I/O error level. i cannot format the partition, Very Important Data.the problem is when i check or do any action on drive it will be take to long and after a while the syslog error appear I/O error and you must turn off the computer and turning on again to able to work a bit with HDD :(

Comment: My first mistake was choosing EXT4 as a filesystem i think its has many bugs,when i run fsck.ext4 or testdisk the filesystem detected as ext3. why? but gparted detected correctly "ext4" in information panel.

Comment: @user179902: that's because `ext4` *is* `ext3` + journaling. Data-wise, the format is the same, so for `fsck` it does not matter.

Comment: @user179902: If there is no `/dev/sdc1` and there are IO Errors everywhere, it's likely the drive has physical errors, and the "Very Import Data" is unrecoverable. But please, paste the output of `fdisk -l` so I can verify the partition layout of that drive.

Comment: Dear my friend here is the fdisk output:                                                         --------------------------------------------------------------------------Disk /dev/sdc: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdc1 1 4294967295 2147483647+ ee GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Comment: I am sorry but could you please tell me how to put many line as a code.to be easy readable

Comment: just select the whole text block you want to format as code and hit CTRL+K

Answer (score 0):

Trying to be useful to other people I had a similar situation with 2 (!) disks attached on a single-board computer with Ubuntu.

I was not able to see some files:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/somewhere/stuff
ls: reading directory /mnt/somewhere/stuff: Input/output error
```

I was not able to mount again the filesystem:

```
$ umount /dev/sdb
$ mount  /dev/sdb /mnt/somewhere
mount: /dev/sdb: can't read superblock
```

I was not able to fix the situation:

```
$ fsck /dev/sdb
Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

I was not able to find any S.M.A.R.T. system error:

```
$ smartctl -t short /dev/sdb
$ smartctl -a /dev/sdb
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6446
```

At the end it was an hardware bug in our powered [USB hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub). I don't know if I can tell the brand here.

In short, **do not trust your USB hub**, even if it is recent and decent. Tell your friends. This is a very nasty problem, that can affect people with a single-board computer such as a RaspberryPI with Ubuntu or other distributions, without the ability to use native proper power supply.

In this case my solution was: buy another USB Hub and anyway buy another single-board computer with native power supply as long term plan.

I'm curious to find out how often these hardware issues happen with Ubuntu. I was not able to test other operating systems so I'm not 100% sure it's an hardware issue.